# Python Tkinter calculator calculation limit

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple calculator that has buttons of numbers 0-9, plus, minus, clear and equals. I have the gui and the functionality of the buttons, but my calculator calculates further than 999. Any ideas?
-I have attempted to stop it calculating further than 999, if you look at line 45-53.

here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Calculator(Frame):

    def frame(this, side): 
        w = Frame(this)
        w.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        return w


    def button(this, root, side, text, command=None): 
        w = Button(root, text=text, command=command) 
        w.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        return w    

    need_clr = False
    def digit(self, digit):
        if self.need_clr:
            self.display.set('')
            self.need_clr = False
        self.display.set(self.display.get() + digit)

    def sign(self):
        need_clr = False
        cont = self.display.get()
        if len(cont) > 0 and cont[0] == '-':
            self.display.set(cont[1:])
        else:
            self.display.set('-' + cont)


    def oper(self, op):
        self.display.set(self.display.get() + ' ' + op + ' ')
        self.need_clr = False

    def calc(self):
        try:
            self.display.set(eval(self.display.get()))
            self.need_clr = True
        except:
            showerror('Operation Error', 'Illegal Operation')
            self.display.set('')
            self.need_clr = False

    def equals(self):
        try:
            result = eval(self.display.get())
            if result >= 1000:
                result (calc)
        except: 
            results("ERROR")
        display.delete(0, END) 
        display.insert(0, display)

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.option_add('*Font', 'Dotum 15')
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title('Simple Calculator')

        self.display = StringVar()
        e = Entry(self, relief=SUNKEN, textvariable=self.display)
        e.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        for key in ("123", "456", "789"):
            keyF = self.frame(TOP)
            for char in key:
                self.button(keyF, LEFT, char,
                            lambda c=char: self.digit(c))

        keyF = self.frame(TOP)
        self.button(keyF, LEFT, '0', lambda ch='0': self.digit(ch))

        opsF = self.frame(TOP)
        for char in "+-=":
            if char == '=':
                btn = self.button(opsF, LEFT, char, self.calc)
            else:
                btn = self.button(opsF, LEFT, char, 
                                  lambda w=self, s=char: w.oper(s))

        clearF = self.frame(BOTTOM)
        self.button(clearF, LEFT, 'Clr', lambda w=self.display: w.set(''))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Calculator().mainloop()
```

Comment: @Totem: line 45-53 are the `equals` method.

Comment: Instead of saying "line 45-53", you should say "the `equals` method". Then we can tell what you're talking about without having to copy and paste your code into `wc` or a text editor or count manually.

Comment: @abarnet Thanks. I still don't get why calculating over 999 isn't desirable though..

Comment: because its something his teacher forced on him Im sure

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about

```
def equals(self):
    try:
        result = eval(self.display.get()) # <-- this is some risky business
        if result >= 1000: #I think you want to check less than but its not clear, this is greater than or equal
            result (calc) #result is a number you cannot do 5(some_argument)
            #^^^^^^^^^^^ this line should probably end up as an error message ...
        #you probably need an else here to handle if the number is too big
        else:
            raise ValueError("Value Too Large!!!")
    except: 
        results("ERROR")  #not sure what this line is doing ...
    display.delete(0, END) 
    display.insert(0, display)
```

there  are several problems  I commented ... perhaps one will solve your issue

but I think really abarnert nailed your problem so I would go with that ...

Answer (score 1):

Your big problem is that you've tried to fix this in a method called `equals` that you never call anywhere in your code. So, obviously this won't do anything.

If you look at where your `=` button is defined, it does this:

```
opsF = self.frame(TOP)
for char in "+-=":
    if char == '=':
        btn = self.button(opsF, LEFT, char, self.calc)
```

So, it calls the `calc` method. You have to change `calc` to influence what it does; adding some completely separate method that never gets called anywhere won't help.

If you change this to call `self.equals` instead of `self.calc`, that solves this first problem… but of course you'll have a whole new set of problems, because most of the code in `equals` makes no sense, as Joran Beasley explains. Look at the *working* code in `calc` as a model for how to do things in `equals`.

However, a better design than copying/pasting/editing `calc` would be to modify it to call some new `validate_result` method, like this:

```
def calc(self):
    try:
        self.display.set(self.validate_result(eval(self.display.get())))
        self.need_clr = True
    except:
        showerror('Operation Error', 'Illegal Operation')
        self.display.set('')
        self.need_clr = False
```

Now, you just need to write `validate_result` as a function that works on numbers and either returns the number (or returns a modified number, if you want) or raises an exception. It doesn't need to duplicate all the work that `calc` does, it can just let `calc` do all that stuff. For example:

```
def validate_result(self, result):
    if result >= 1000:
        raise ValueError('result too big!')
    else:
        return result
```